# Core Data function similar to the WHERE='(sql query)'

Tags: objective-c, sql, core-data, nspredicate

How can run sql query CoreData similar this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM headphones WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM old_headphones);
```

I read NSPredicate guide and NSExpression, but don't understand how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct headphones.Id) 
FROM headphones 
    INNER JOIN old_headphones ON
        headphones.Id = old_headphones.Id
```

When there is not an n-to_1 relation between headphones and old_headphones, you can omit the DISTINCT.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*First request*/
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                               entityForName:@"headphones" inManagedObjectContext:yourContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSError *error;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [yourContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

/*2nd request*/
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest2 = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity2 = [NSEntityDescription 
                               entityForName:@"old_headphones" inManagedObjectContext:yourContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity2];

NSError *error;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [yourContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest2 error:&error];

//use your 2 NSArray to find your headphones
```